Hidden Markov Model in hmmlearn Not Converging
I'm using the hmmlearn library to fit a Hidden Markov Model (HMM) to a dataset I've generated, but I'm encountering an issue where the model does not converge. Below is my code:
a = np.array([
    [0.7, 0.2, 0.1],
    [0.3, 0.5, 0.2],
    [0.3, 0.3, 0.4]
])

b = np.array(
    [[0.6, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1],
     [0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.2],
     [0.1, 0.1, 0.6, 0.2]]
)

pi = np.array([0.3, 0.4, 0.3])

model = MarkovModel(transition_probabilities=a, emission_probabilities=b, initial_state_distribution=pi)

observations = np.array([model.generate_observation_sequence(sequence_length=10) for _ in range(1_000)])

MarkovModel is my class (https://github.com/SuperrMurlocc/hmm.git) but all it does is it generates set of sequences of observations, here is an example (not exactly 1000 sequences due to stackoverflow's character limit):
[[2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 2, 0],
[0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 0, 1, 1, 2],
[0, 1, 0, 0, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0],
[2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 3, 3],
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 0, 0, 1],
[3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 0, 0, 3, 1],
[0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 3, 0, 2, 0, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
[2, 0, 2, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
[0, 1, 0, 0, 3, 2, 2, 0, 3, 3],
[0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 3, 1],
[0, 0, 3, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 0, 0],
[3, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 2, 1],
[3, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
[2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1],
[1, 3, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2],
[1, 3, 1, 3, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2],
[2, 3, 0, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2],
[2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1],
[2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 2, 3],
[2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2],
[3, 1, 0, 2, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0],
[1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0],
[2, 2, 3, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1],
[3, 0, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 0, 1, 0],
[2, 0, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 3],
[0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 3],
[3, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
[0, 1, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
[2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2],
[2, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 2],
[3, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 0, 3, 1],
[2, 2, 0, 3, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
[2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2],
[3, 0, 0, 2, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2],
[0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
[3, 2, 2, 1, 0, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1],
[0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
[0, 2, 0, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0],
[0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 1, 2],
[3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 0, 3, 1, 2],
[0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 2, 0],
[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 0, 3],
[1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3],
[1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 1, 0, 2, 0, 2],
[0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 3, 2, 0],
[0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 3, 1, 0, 1, 0],
[0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 0],
[1, 3, 0, 2, 1, 2, 1, 0, 3, 3],
[2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 3, 1],
[1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 3],
[3, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 2, 1],
[1, 2, 1, 0, 3, 0, 2, 3, 2, 0],
[0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2],
[3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3],
[3, 0, 3, 1, 3, 0, 2, 1, 2, 1],
[0, 3, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 1],
[1, 0, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1],
[2, 3, 1, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[2, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2],
[3, 2, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 2, 3],
[3, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 3, 2, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[1, 2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2],
[1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 3, 1],
[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 0],
[1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 3, 1, 1, 0, 3],
[2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0],
[1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1, 0, 2],
[0, 2, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
[2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 2],
[3, 2, 2, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3],
[1, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
[3, 0, 2, 3, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3],
[3, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 0],
[3, 3, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2],
[1, 1, 0, 1, 3, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
[2, 3, 2, 0, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3],
[2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 0, 2, 0, 3],
[0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1, 1, 1],
[1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 1, 3],
[3, 0, 3, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[3, 2, 1, 3, 0, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0],
[0, 2, 0, 0, 3, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0],
[1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0],
[3, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1],
[2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 1, 0, 1],
[1, 2, 1, 2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1],
[1, 0, 3, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1],
[0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 3],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3],
[2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 1, 2, 0],
[0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 3, 0, 0, 2, 2],
[0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2],
[1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 3],
[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1],
[3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 0, 0, 3],
[1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3],
[0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 0, 3],
[1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
[0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 3, 1],
[3, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 1],
[0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
[3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 3, 0],
[0, 1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1],
[2, 3, 0, 2, 3, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0],
[1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 3],
[2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 0],
[0, 2, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 0, 1],
[3, 3, 2, 0, 0, 2, 3, 2, 0, 2],
[3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
[2, 2, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 3, 1, 1],
[3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 0, 3, 3, 3],
[2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 0, 0],
[1, 0, 3, 3, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 2],
[3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2],
[0, 0, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 0, 2, 2],
[1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[1, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 3],
[2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0],
[2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 0],
[2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 3, 3],
[2, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 3, 2, 0, 2],
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 1],
[2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2],
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3],
[3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 3, 1, 1],
[1, 0, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 0, 0, 3],
[1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 0, 1],
[1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2],
[3, 1, 2, 3, 0, 3, 1, 0, 0, 2],
[2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 0, 3, 2, 3],
[0, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0],
[1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 0],
[3, 0, 3, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
[2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 0],
[2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 0],
[0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 2, 3],
[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0],
[0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 3, 0, 2, 0, 2],
[3, 0, 1, 3, 2, 3, 3, 0, 0, 3],
[2, 3, 0, 1, 0, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3],
[2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 3, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2],
[1, 3, 1, 3, 2, 3, 3, 0, 2, 0],
[3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 3],
[3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3],
[3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 3],
[2, 0, 2, 0, 3, 1, 3, 0, 3, 1],
[1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2],
[2, 3, 2, 0, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2],
[2, 3, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 3, 0],
[1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1],
[2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 0, 1, 3, 3, 0],
[0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 1],
[2, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 2, 3, 0, 0],
[0, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0],
[2, 2, 0, 1, 0, 3, 2, 2, 1, 0],
[1, 0, 2, 2, 1, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0],
[2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 1, 0, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 0],
[1, 2, 0, 1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2],
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3],
[0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1],
[0, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 0, 1, 0, 3],
[0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0],
[1, 0, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 0, 1],
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
[3, 2, 1, 3, 0, 3, 1, 0, 0, 3],
[2, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 0, 1, 0, 3],
[1, 1, 1, 3, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 3],
[2, 0, 0, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
[3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0],
[2, 2, 3, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0],
[2, 0, 0, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1],
[0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0, 0, 1, 3],
[2, 3, 1, 2, 0, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1],
[1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 3],
[1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 2, 1],
[0, 1, 0, 3, 3, 0, 3, 0, 2, 3],
[2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1],
[3, 3, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1],
[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3],
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
[1, 3, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 3, 0, 3],
[1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 3],
[0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 1],
[0, 0, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1],
[0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0],
[0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1],
[3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 2, 0],
[0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1],
[1, 0, 2, 3, 0, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1],
[1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 3, 1, 1, 1],
[3, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2],
[1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1, 3],
[2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 0, 0],
[0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 2],
[3, 0, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 3, 1],
[0, 3, 0, 3, 2, 3, 3, 0, 3, 3],
[1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 3, 1, 2, 3, 0],
[3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2],
[1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1],
[0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 3],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0],
[0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 3],
[0, 2, 3, 0, 1, 0, 3, 2, 0, 2],
[0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 3],
[0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 3, 0, 3, 1, 1],
[2, 2, 3, 0, 2, 3, 1, 0, 3, 2],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 3, 0, 0, 1],
[2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 3, 3, 1, 0, 2],
[1, 0, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 3, 0],
[0, 0, 2, 3, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 2],
[1, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 3, 3],
[2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2],
[3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1],
[2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 0, 1],
[3, 2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0],
[0, 2, 3, 0, 3, 1, 3, 0, 1, 1],
[3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 3],
[2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1],
[2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0],
[1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2],
[3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[1, 3, 2, 0, 2, 3, 1, 1, 0, 1],
[3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3],
[1, 0, 2, 0, 2, 3, 2, 0, 3, 2],
[2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 0, 2, 0, 1],
[3, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1],
[2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 0, 1, 3, 2],
[2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1],
[1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0],
[3, 2, 3, 0, 3, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1],
[3, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 3, 2, 3],
[2, 0, 2, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0],
[2, 3, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1],
[3, 3, 1, 0, 1, 3, 3, 0, 2, 2],
[1, 3, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 0, 2],
[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1],
[3, 0, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0],
[2, 1, 0, 2, 3, 0, 0, 3, 2, 0],
[0, 3, 3, 1, 0, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2],
[1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 0, 0, 3, 1],
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 3, 1, 0, 1],
[1, 1, 3, 2, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2],
[3, 3, 2, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 2],
[1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2],
[2, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
[2, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
[0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 3, 3, 0],
[1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 0, 2, 0],
[2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 2],
[2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 2, 2, 0],
[2, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1],
[1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2],
[1, 0, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 3, 0],
[2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 0, 0],
[0, 3, 2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2],
[0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 0, 3, 2, 1],
[0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 3, 0, 2],
[2, 2, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 0, 3],
[0, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 3, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 1, 0, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1],
[3, 2, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 3, 2, 2],
[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0],
[3, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 0, 3, 2, 0],
[0, 3, 1, 3, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0],
[2, 1, 3, 3, 0, 2, 3, 0, 0, 1],
[2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2],
[1, 2, 0, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1],
[2, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
[1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[2, 0, 0, 3, 3, 0, 1, 0, 2, 2],
[3, 3, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
[1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 0, 3, 0, 1, 2],
[2, 2, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
[0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2],
[0, 0, 3, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
[3, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2],
[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2],
[1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 0, 0, 2],
[3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3],
[1, 3, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
[0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2],
[2, 3, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
[2, 3, 2, 0, 0, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1],
[0, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 3, 3],
[2, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3],
[2, 2, 1, 2, 0, 3, 1, 0, 3, 2],
[3, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2],
[0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2],
[0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 3, 1, 0, 0],
[2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2],
[1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1],
[1, 1, 3, 3, 0, 3, 1, 3, 3, 0],
[3, 2, 0, 1, 3, 2, 0, 2, 1, 2],
[2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3],
[0, 0, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1],
[3, 2, 0, 0, 3, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
[2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3],
[3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0],
[1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2],
[1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 1, 1],
[0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 3],
[2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 3, 2, 2],
[3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 0, 3, 0, 2],
[0, 1, 0, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 2],
[2, 0, 3, 1, 1, 3, 0, 3, 1, 1],
[3, 0, 0, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 0],
[0, 2, 1, 3, 0, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1],
[2, 0, 1, 1, 3, 2, 3, 0, 0, 3],
[0, 1, 3, 1, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1],
[2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 3, 0],
[0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 3, 1],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 0, 1, 2],
[3, 1, 3, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2],
[0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
[3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 1, 1, 0, 2],
[0, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0],
[3, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 3, 2, 2, 0, 2],
[2, 3, 3, 1, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 1, 0, 0, 3, 3, 1, 2, 0, 1],
[2, 1, 2, 3, 0, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1],
[0, 0, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0],
[2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 3, 2],
[0, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0],
[2, 0, 3, 2, 3, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2],
[3, 3, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2],
[1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1],
[1, 0, 3, 0, 2, 1, 3, 0, 3, 3],
[2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[2, 0, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 2],
[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1],
[2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
[3, 2, 0, 3, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1, 3],
[0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1],
[2, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
[1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1],
[3, 0, 0, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1],
[2, 3, 3, 3, 0, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1],
[1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0],
[0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 3, 2, 1, 0],
[3, 3, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
[0, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2],
[0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 0],
[2, 0, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 0, 0],
[2, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 0],
[3, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0],
[2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 0],
[3, 2, 0, 2, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2],
[3, 2, 1, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0, 2, 0],
[2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 3],
[0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2],
[2, 3, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0],
[2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3],
[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0],
[3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0],
[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 3],
[3, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
[1, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0],
[3, 0, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 0],
[1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2],
[2, 3, 1, 0, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2, 0],
[2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1],
[2, 1, 0, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 0, 0],
[3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1],
[1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 3, 1, 0],
[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3],
[2, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 0, 1, 3, 3],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1],
[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1],
[2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 3, 2, 0],
[0, 3, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1],
[1, 2, 3, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1],
[2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3],
[2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 3, 0, 2, 2, 2],
[2, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2],
[1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 3, 1, 0],
[1, 0, 0, 3, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1],
[3, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2],
[1, 2, 2, 3, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0],
[0, 3, 0, 2, 1, 0, 3, 1, 0, 0],
[1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
[1, 2, 0, 3, 2, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2],
[0, 1, 3, 2, 2, 0, 1, 3, 1, 2],
[2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0],
[0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 3],
[3, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 3, 3, 1],
[0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 2],
[0, 2, 3, 1, 0, 2, 2, 3, 1, 0],
[2, 0, 3, 0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 0, 1],
[0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 2],
[1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 0, 3, 2, 3, 1],
[0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 0, 3],
[2, 0, 1, 3, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 3],
[2, 0, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[1, 2, 1, 0, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 1],
[3, 0, 1, 3, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1],
[2, 0, 0, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1],
[3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2],
[1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 1, 3],
[2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[2, 2, 3, 0, 3, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
[2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 3, 1],
[0, 3, 2, 0, 2, 3, 2, 3, 0, 0],
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 0],
[1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 1, 1],
[1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 3, 3],
[2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0],
[1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 3],
[2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 3, 0, 0, 2],
[3, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2],
[3, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0],
[0, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0],
[0, 0, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[3, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 0],
[3, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2],
[0, 0, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 0, 0],
[3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
[3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 0, 3, 2],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 0],
[2, 0, 1, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
[0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0],
[3, 3, 0, 1, 1, 3, 2, 0, 0, 1],
[1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2],
[0, 1, 3, 2, 0, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1],
[0, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0],
[2, 3, 3, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0],
[0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2],
[0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1, 2],
[1, 0, 3, 3, 1, 0, 1, 3, 1, 2],
[1, 0, 3, 3, 1, 3, 0, 3, 2, 2],
[3, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 2, 0],
[0, 2, 3, 0, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 0],
[2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
[2, 2, 3, 3, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2],
[2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 2, 0, 0],
[1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 3, 3, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 3, 0, 2, 0],
[0, 3, 2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2],
[1, 2, 0, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 0, 0],
[0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
[2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[2, 0, 1, 3, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3],
[1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
[2, 0, 2, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 0, 1],
[2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3],
[1, 2, 0, 3, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1],
[0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0],
[0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2],
[0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2],
[2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1, 1],
[0, 1, 2, 0, 3, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0],
[1, 3, 3, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 0],
[2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1],
[2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 0],
[1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2],
[3, 0, 0, 3, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2],
[3, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
[3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0],
[1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3],
[1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3],
[2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 3, 3, 0],
[3, 0, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 0, 0, 1],
[3, 1, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2],
[1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0],
[0, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1, 2, 3, 0, 2],
[2, 1, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
[0, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0],
[1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1],
[2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0],
[2, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 3, 0, 2, 1],
[0, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 0],
[0, 3, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 0, 1],
[3, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 1],
[2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0],
[0, 0, 3, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 2],
[2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1],
[0, 3, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0],
[3, 3, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 3],
[0, 0, 3, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0],
[0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 3, 1],
[0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 3, 1, 2, 1, 0],
[1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2],
[2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0],
[0, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 3, 2, 1, 1],
[0, 0, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
[3, 0, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3],
[2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 1],
[0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 3, 1, 0, 0, 1],
[0, 3, 2, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
[2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 0, 0, 3, 3, 0],
[2, 0, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 2],
[2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 3, 3, 0],
[1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3],
[2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 0, 0],
[2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 3],
[1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 0, 2, 0, 2],
[0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0],
[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 3, 2],
[0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0],
[0, 1, 3, 0, 3, 2, 0, 0, 1, 3],
[2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3],
[0, 0, 3, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1],
[0, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 3, 2, 0, 3, 2, 3, 1, 0, 2],
[2, 1, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 3, 1, 0],
[2, 3, 2, 0, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1],
[3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2],
[2, 3, 0, 3, 3, 3, 0, 2, 0, 0],
[1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 3, 1],
[3, 3, 0, 0, 3, 0, 2, 3, 0, 3],
[2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 3, 0, 2, 0, 0],
[0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 2, 0],
[2, 0, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
[0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 2],
[0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 3, 2, 0, 3, 2],
[2, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 3],
[0, 0, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 0, 2, 0],
[2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0],
[3, 2, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2],
[2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 0, 0, 3],
[3, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 1, 1, 2],
[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2],
[0, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1],
[2, 3, 1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 1, 2, 2],
[3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
[2, 3, 3, 0, 1, 0, 1, 3, 1, 0],
[1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0],
[0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 3, 2, 1, 2],
[0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2, 1, 2, 2],
[2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
[2, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 0],
[1, 3, 2, 1, 0, 3, 2, 2, 1, 0],
[0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 3, 1],
[2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1],
[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1],
[3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 0, 3, 2, 0],
[0, 1, 0, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 3, 0],
[2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0],
[2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3],
[3, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1],
[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1],
[2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0],
[0, 1, 1, 0, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0],
[1, 0, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
[3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 2],
[0, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 0],
[0, 3, 2, 1, 0, 2, 0, 2, 3, 1],
[2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
[1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 3],
[1, 1, 0, 3, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 0],
[2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 3, 1, 2, 1, 0],
[1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 0],
[2, 3, 3, 0, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 0],
[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0],
[2, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[1, 0, 1, 0, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 0],
[0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 3, 0, 2, 2],
[1, 0, 1, 0, 3, 2, 3, 3, 0, 0],
[2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0],
[0, 3, 0, 3, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 3, 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0],
[2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0],
[2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 2],
[3, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2],
[1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0],
[2, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1],
[2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2],
[0, 3, 0, 1, 1, 3, 2, 0, 1, 0],
[0, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 1],
[0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1],
[1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0],
[3, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 1, 3, 0, 3, 3, 2, 0, 1],
[1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1],
[3, 1, 0, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
[1, 2, 0, 0, 3, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3],
[2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[1, 3, 3, 0, 2, 3, 3, 0, 0, 3],
[1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2],
[0, 3, 0, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2],
[0, 0, 3, 2, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
[1, 2, 1, 0, 3, 2, 3, 3, 0, 2],
[1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 3],
[3, 3, 0, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1],
[0, 3, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2],
[2, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[1, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 3, 2, 0],
[2, 2, 3, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 3, 2],
[0, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3],
[0, 1, 1, 0, 3, 1, 3, 0, 1, 0],
[1, 0, 0, 3, 3, 1, 0, 2, 3, 1],
[3, 1, 2, 3, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 0],
[1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 0, 3, 2, 0, 2],
[3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
[2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 3],
[0, 3, 3, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 2],
[2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 3, 1, 3],
[3, 0, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 0],
[1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 0],
[0, 3, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0],
[3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0],
[0, 3, 3, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 3],
[2, 0, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2],
[2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 1],
[1, 3, 1, 0, 3, 0, 3, 1, 0, 1],
[1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0],
[2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 3],
[2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 3, 0, 2, 1],
[0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2],
[1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1],
[2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0],
[3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0],
[2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2],
[2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1],
[2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0],
[0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 1, 3, 0],
[1, 2, 0, 2, 3, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
[1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 0, 1, 2, 2],
[1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 3, 2, 1],
[1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 3, 1, 0],
[1, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 3],
[2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[2, 3, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 3, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 3],
[0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 3],
[0, 3, 2, 3, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
[1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2],
[3, 1, 3, 2, 0, 0, 2, 1, 3, 2],
[2, 2, 0, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0],
[0, 3, 3, 1, 0, 0, 3, 1, 1, 2],
[0, 3, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0],
[0, 2, 1, 3, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 3],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2],
[1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2],
[1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2],
[1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 0, 3, 0, 0],
[3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 0, 3, 3, 3, 2],
[2, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2],
[0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
[3, 2, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1],
[0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 0, 0, 3],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3, 1, 0, 1],
[3, 2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 2],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 1],
[1, 0, 3, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
[2, 3, 2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 3, 1],
[0, 2, 2, 3, 0, 3, 0, 0, 3, 0],
[2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 0, 1, 3, 2, 2],
[1, 1, 0, 3, 2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 1],
[0, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
[1, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3],
[1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0],
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 3, 2],
[3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[0, 3, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0],
[1, 0, 3, 3, 1, 3, 0, 2, 2, 2],
[3, 1, 0, 1, 3, 3, 0, 2, 0, 1],
[1, 3, 3, 0, 2, 3, 3, 3, 0, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0],
[3, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2],
[2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1],
[2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 2, 1, 0],
[0, 0, 2, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 3],
[2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 0],
[1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 0, 3],
[0, 3, 1, 3, 0, 0, 3, 3, 1, 0],
[0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0],
[2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 3],
[2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0],
[3, 0, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
[2, 0, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0],
[2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 2],
[3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0],
[2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 3, 3, 2],
[1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 0, 0],
[0, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 0, 3, 0, 2],
[3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 0, 0, 3, 2],
[0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0],
[2, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1],
[0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 0, 1, 0, 2],
[2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
[2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0],
[1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[0, 2, 3, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
[0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 0, 0, 3, 0],
[1, 3, 3, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 2, 3],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0],
[0, 3, 1, 0, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2],
[2, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 0, 0, 1, 3],
[1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0],
[1, 3, 3, 3, 0, 3, 1, 1, 1, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0],
[3, 0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3],
[1, 2, 1, 2, 0, 1, 3, 2, 0, 1],
[2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],
[2, 2, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 1],
[1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0],
[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2],
[1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 3, 2, 0],
[2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0],
[2, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0],
[0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 3],
[0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2],
[1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 0],
[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 3, 0],
[0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2],
[0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0],
[2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
[3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[3, 0, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 1],
[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
[2, 0, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 0],
[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1],
[1, 2, 3, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2],
[1, 1, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2],
[2, 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 3, 0],
[1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2],
[1, 0, 2, 2, 3, 1, 0, 3, 2, 0],
[0, 0, 3, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0],
[2, 0, 0, 3, 1, 0, 3, 2, 2, 0],
[1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 3],
[1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1],
[0, 2, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1],
[1, 0, 1, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 3, 2, 1],
[0, 0, 3, 2, 1, 3, 0, 1, 0, 2],
[1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
[2, 3, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
[3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 3, 1, 2],

and the rest of the code, so trying to remodel:
concatenated = np.concatenate(observations.reshape(10, 1_000))

remodel = hmm.CategoricalHMM(n_components=3, n_iter=100, verbose=True)

remodel.fit(concatenated.reshape(-1, 1), lengths=[10 for _ in range(1_000)])

No matter what i try i get shitty remodel.emissionprob_ and remodel.transmat_ very close to
[[.33 .33. 33],
[.33 .33. 33],
[.33 .33. 33]]

Also the following warning occurs very often:
Model is not converging.

I've already tried:

generating sequences with CategoricalHMM;
initializing transmat_, emissionprob_ and start_prob by hand by adding init_params parameter;
changing shapes of set of sequences of observations (1000x10, 10x1000, 1x10000 and so on);
using MultinomialHMM and remodel.fit(observations).


Can you provide the code for MarkovModel ? Want to rule out any bugs in that first before thinking about convergence.

@SachinHosmani Sure thing, there you go: https://github.com/SuperrMurlocc/hmm.git. but as I mentioned the same error occurs when i generate sequences using hmm.CategoricalHMM so I doubt that's it.

Ok sorry I missed that. Then it's worth editing your post to replace your custom class with CategoricalHMM to generate the sequences to make it as minimal a problem for the community to work with.

I don't know wether it's my machine or not, but what solved the problem for me was changing numpy package version to 1.26.4.

We had the same issue. I think it may be a bug in the hmmlearn package or because of some changes in numpy between 1.26.4 and 2.0.0. I have created an issue on their github about this, since their example code does not work with the latest version of numpy

I used CategoricalHMM to generate sequences and was able to fairly easily make it converge to some degree
import numpy as np
from hmmlearn.hmm import CategoricalHMM

transition_probabilities = np.array([
    [0.7, 0.2, 0.1],
    [0.3, 0.5, 0.2],
    [0.3, 0.3, 0.4]
])

emission_probabilities = np.array([
    [0.6, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1],
    [0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.2],
    [0.1, 0.1, 0.6, 0.2]
])

initial_state_distribution = np.array([0.3, 0.4, 0.3])

n_states = transition_probabilities.shape[0]

model = CategoricalHMM(n_components=n_states, n_iter=100)

model.startprob_ = initial_state_distribution
model.transmat_ = transition_probabilities
model.emissionprob_ = emission_probabilities

sequence_length = 10
n_sequences = 1000

observations = np.array([model.sample(sequence_length)[0] for _ in range(n_sequences)])

concatenated = np.concatenate(observations).reshape(-1, 1)

remodel = CategoricalHMM(n_components=3, n_iter=20000, tol=1e-6, verbose=True)

remodel.fit(concatenated, lengths=[10] * 1_000)

print("Learned start probabilities:")
print(remodel.startprob_)
print("actual start probabilities:")
print(initial_state_distribution)

print("Learned transition matrix:")
print(remodel.transmat_)
print("actual transition matrix:")
print(transition_probabilities)

print("Learned emission matrix:")
print(remodel.emissionprob_)
print("actual emission matrix:")
print(emission_probabilities)



Output
Learned start probabilities:
[0.46515283 0.40011551 0.13473165]
actual start probabilities:
[0.3 0.4 0.3]
Learned transition matrix:
[[0.66645301 0.31801032 0.01553668]
 [0.54318954 0.33546511 0.12134534]
 [0.17781337 0.54636086 0.27582578]]
actual transition matrix:
[[0.7 0.2 0.1]
 [0.3 0.5 0.2]
 [0.3 0.3 0.4]]
Learned emission matrix:
[[6.42087313e-01 1.67261776e-01 2.01852929e-04 1.90449058e-01]
 [6.60855229e-05 4.21539522e-01 5.78372265e-01 2.21279145e-05]
 [1.14848278e-11 9.09915038e-27 4.15166263e-01 5.84833737e-01]]
actual emission matrix:
[[0.6 0.2 0.1 0.1]
 [0.2 0.4 0.2 0.2]
 [0.1 0.1 0.6 0.2]]

It did not use the full 20k iterations I had asked because the tolerance limit was breached after around 10k iterations. If you further reduce the tolerance limit it would converge further.

Thank you. I used your example and found out that it does work on numpy 1.26.4 but not on the newest version. Thanks for your effort.
